# Why can't I log exceptions using logging.info?

Tags: python, exception, logging

For example, this bit of code below works as expected:

```
import logging
import sys

def infologAllUncaught(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    logging.error("Uncaught exception", exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))

sys.excepthook = infologAllUncaught

raise Exception("WOAH THERE!")
```

returning:

```
ERROR:root:Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\proj\cedu_ui\product\trunk\test\tools\genie\genie\logging_test2.py", line 9, in <module>
    raise Exception("WOAH THERE!")
Exception: WOAH THERE!
```

---

However, this bit of code returns nothing.

```
import logging
import sys

def infologAllUncaught(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    logging.info("Uncaught exception", exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))

sys.excepthook = infologAllUncaught

raise Exception("WOAH THERE!")
```

It seems like all the logging methods except logging.exception have the same usage in the API, so I'm not sure why these are yielding different results.

Comment: Is your root logger configured to log at the info level?

Comment: Ref https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#when-to-use-logging "The default level is WARNING ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to configure your logger to log at INFO level, the default is only WARNING.

Ref: docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#when-to-use-logging "The default level is WARNING ..."

You might want to look at using something like this https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file to do the initial logger configuration.